# How does second-order arithmetic rule out non-standard numbers?

Tags: arithmetic, model-theory, peano-axioms, nonstandard-models, second-order-logic

According to [1](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/) there are axioms of second-order arithmetic which categorically characterize the natural numbers up to isomorphism. The axioms are:

$$\forall x\,\neg(x+1=0)$$
$$\forall x\,\forall y(x+1=y+1\to x=y)$$
$$\forall X\left(\left[X(0) \land \forall y\left(X(y) \to X(y+1)\right)\right] \to \forall y\,X(y)\right)$$

Only the last axiom uses second-order logic. It is the induction axiom, which in first-order arithmetic is replaced by an induction axiom schema.

These axioms of second-order arithmetic rule out "non-standard numbers" which are compatible with first-order arithmetic. Such non-standard numbers are numbers which have infinitely many predecessors and are larger than any natural number.

But how does the second order induction axiom rule out non-standard numbers, in contrast to the first-order induction schema? Since the second-order axioms talks about "all properties" $X$, I assume non-standard models must have at least one property $\Phi$ which contradicts the second-order induction axiom. But what is this property $\Phi$?

Comment: The property $\Phi$ is "being a standard number".

Comment: The property you are looking for is exactly **standardness**.

Comment: If one treats second order logic as a two-typed first order logic, one does get nonstandard models that do satisfy your induction axiom. But these nonstandard models must not contain the predicate "is a standard number" in their second-order part to avoid exactly this issue. Alas, in "true" second order logic all predicates (corresponding to all subsets of the first order part) are allowed.

Comment: Oh thank you, "is a standard number" makes indeed sense! I guess "has finitely many predecessors" would also work, right? Since non-standard numbers have infinitely many predecessors.

Comment: @Max Yes, that's right.